# Server and client on a device with WiFi-hotspot enabled

Tags: android, wifi, tethering

Is it possible to enable WiFi tethering/hotspot on an android phone and configure it to be a server as well as client through two different apps?

Comment: you mean client as in Wifi-Client or as in TCP/UDP-Client?

Comment: As in TCP/UDP client...

Comment: Ys, it's possible

Answer (score 1):

*You don't need two different application. Integrate two functions in one app.*

Use `java.net.Socket` for client-side implementation and `java.net.ServerSocket` for server-side implementation.

***Server-Side Code:***

Call `startServer()` to start server listening for data at port **9809**(Put as you wish).

```
void startServer() throws IOException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9809);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DataInputStream stream = null;
            try {
                if (socket != null) {
                    stream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String gotdata = null;
            try {
                if (stream != null) {
                    gotdata = stream.readUTF();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                assert socket != null;
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("THE DATA WE HAVE GOT :"+gotdata)

        }).start();
```

***Client-Side Code:***
Here, You should put the IP address of the device acting as server in line 6(For my case, it was 192.168.1.100).

Call `sendData()` to send data to the device acting as server.

```
void sendData() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 9809);
                DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                stream.writeUTF("Some data here");
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
                socket.close();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Done!");
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Fail!");
                    }
                });
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```